# Flexible HTML Tag in a Laravel Blade Component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have created a blade component that I sometimes need to render as an a tag and other times as a button.  To accomplish that, I have created the following component:

```
@props([
  'number',
  'tag' => 'a'
])

@php
  $classes = 'text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100 block px-4 py-2 text-sm';
@endphp

@if ($tag === 'a')
  <a
    tabindex="-1"
    role="menuitem"
    id="menu-item-{{ $number }}"
    class="{{ $classes }}"
    {{ $attributes }}
  >
    {{ $slot }}
  </a>

@else
  <button
    type="submit"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="menuitem"
    id="menu-item-{{ $number }}"
    class="{{ $classes }} w-full text-left"
  >
    {{ $slot }}
  </button>
@endif
```

Now, this works, but it is not very DRY.  I am wondering, therefore, if there is a DRYer and more elegant way for me to accomplish the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would do this using JavaScript using createElement.

Answer (score 0):

First note this possibility

```
@php
    $tag = 'a';
@endphp
<{{ $tag }}>yo</{{ $tag }}>
```

But my preferred way is to use smaller components (micro components?) which will help you refactor the shared attributes.

```
@php
    $classes = 'text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100 block px-4 py-2 text-sm';
@endphp

@if ($tag === 'a')

    <x-a class="{{ $classes }}" {{ $attributes }}>
        {{ $slot }}
    </x-a>

@else

    <x-button class="{{ $classes }}"> {{-- w-full text-left GETS MERGERD--}}
        {{ $slot }}
    </x-button>
    
@endif
```